# Openpyxl using a created named range string as the data for a chart

Tags: charts, range, openpyxl, named

Using the openpyxl module, I create a excel workbook and write data to the file.
In the worksheet labeled Data, I make a table and each column in the table I use the womb.create_named_range code to make a string that corresponds to a range of data in the sheet.

Then I want to make a chart where I use the named ranges as the x and y data

So I would have the x data as “=Data!xAxis” for example.

I want to do this so that if the user adds new rows the the table in excel, the named range expands and the charts update automatically. However when putting the named range string into Reference() for the chart series I get an error that it needs to have int within the string for the reference module to make the excel formula.

Comment: I don't think that is currently possible.

Comment: Is there any type of work around to try and make? I don't see why there should be anything too hard to do this. Just want to put a string in the field for the xData source and let openpyxl not try and extract information from it. Essentially just tell openpyxl to ignore any errors from it and hope the named range is in the excel sheet when the user opens it

Comment: also if xlsxwriter can do this, or another excel writing module can, that would work too

Comment: For anyone who wants to do this in the future, I found a work around. First you make essentially a dummy Reference() and Series() then you edit inside the series before adding to chart:

ref = Reference(range_string = "=data!$A$2:$A$10")
series = Series(ref,ref)
#Edit with named range
series.yVal.numRef.f = "=data!yData"
series.xVal.numRef.f = "=data!xData"